# Redirect to some page using AngularJs while closing bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login History</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                        <legend class="scheduler-border" style="color: #4682B4">Message</legend>
                        <div>
                            Total Unsuccessful login attempts : 0
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Last Successful login attempt : <br />
                            Datetime :  27-7-2015 10:25:52<br />
                            Access IP Address ::1<br />
                            User Name : {{UserName}}<br />
                            <br>
                            Last Unsuccessful login attempt : <br />
                            NONE
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

On click of login button I open the modal using Jquery.

Now once modal is hide(either by clicking on Close button or by clicking outside modal) I need to redirect to some other page

How can I do that.

Below is my code.

```
JITManagementApp.controller('AuthenticationController',
function AuthenticationController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.UserName = "amit";

    $scope.Login = function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $location.path("/manageSite");
        })
    }
```

});

Code to redirect is

```
 $location.path("/manageSite");
```

but still it is not redirecting to manageSite ?

Comment: try using `$state.go('/manageSite')`